# About conditional type 3

Tags: conditionals

> If the first vampire came into existence that day and bit one person a month, there would have been two vampires by February 1st, 1600.

Doesn't this sentence have to be "if the first vampire had come into existence ~~" because it's talking about the past?

Comment: It's very common to use simple past in casual contexts where the grammar books would tell you to use past perfect. There are lots of questions about this.

Comment: English does not have numbered conditionals. That's just a poor crutch inflicted on [ell.se] so they don't create monstrosities. Native speakers have never heard of such a thing and are not bound by it.

Comment: @tchrist You're not wrong, but that's a bit much to throw at a new user here who's just repeating what every ESL book and English teacher they've ever had has told them. There's nothing unclear about using the term "third conditional" here.

Comment: @도라에몽1 The sentence would be *better* with past perfect there, but it's natural enough to use simple past there in speaking or casual writing. If this is formal writing, a good editor would fix it as you suggest.

Comment: @gotube Would things be changed if 'If' was 'Supposed that'?